# Within a table in R, how can I multiple all the values in a row by a value?

Tags: r

I've created the following table in R:

```
Table1 <- 
matrix(c(0.3,0.6,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.6),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
rownames(Table1)<-c("1st graders","6th graders", "11th graders")
colnames(Table1)<-c("Ice Cream","Fruit","French Fries")
Table1<-as.table(Table1)
Table1
               Ice Cream      Fruit        French Fries
1st graders        0.3         0.6          0.1
6th graders        0.6         0.3          0.1
11th graders       0.3         0.1          0.6
```

I now want to multiply all the values in row 1 by a number, values in row 2 by a number etc to produce a new table with the same rows/columns but with the updated values.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for what to do when someone answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sweep`

```
val <- c(0, 1, 10)
sweep(Table1, 1, val, "*")
#             Ice Cream Fruit French Fries
#1st graders        0.0   0.0          0.0
#6th graders        0.6   0.3          0.1
#11th graders       3.0   1.0          6.0
```

In above the 1'st row is multiplied by 0, the second by 1 and the third by 10.

As noted below in the comments,

```
Table1 * val
#             Ice Cream Fruit French Fries
#1st graders        0.0   0.0          0.0
#6th graders        0.6   0.3          0.1
#11th graders       3.0   1.0          6.0
```

achives the same result as well.

Comment: `sweep` is awesome and a flexible solution, but since this is row-wise, you can just do `Table1 * c(0,1,10)` since matrices fill column-wise

Comment: Yes, I liked it for the flexibility.